# JSON encoding multi selected rows into an array

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on the following snippet. How can I load all affected rows into `$items` array?

As you can see I am able to fetch each binded cell like `$pid` and `$psku` but I need to load them to  $items

```
$items =[];
$stmt = $conn -> prepare("SELECT `pid`,`psku` FROM `appolo` ORDER BY `pid` ASC LIMIT 24");

$stmt -> execute();
$stmt -> store_result();
$stmt -> bind_result($pid, $psku);

while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
    echo $pid;
    echo $psku;
}
$stmt->free_result(); 

echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: Use [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) instead of echoing them?

Comment: So what's the problem - [] notation already invented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just build an array of the variables and add to an array:

```
while ($stmt -> fetch()) {
    $items[] = array($pid, $psku);
}
```

To get an associative array:

```
    $items[] = compact('pid', 'psku');
```

Comment: Thanks  AbraCadaver this was exactly what I was looking for